# Crystal Reports Viewer of windows forms not working after upgrade .net from 4 to 4.6

Tags: crystal-reports, report, .net-4.6

My existing code work as expected with .net framework 4. But after upgrade to .net 4.6. Its not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran into this. Had to uninstall all 4.6 frameworks, and then re-install 4.5.2 Framework. And finally re-register in IIS by running aspnet_regiis -i

and then my CR started working again.

So removing 4.6 for Windows 2008 Server is the solution. For Windows 2012 Server, turns out the 4.6 is "hidden" as update KB3102467 that was pushed out around April 2017. Uninstalling that got the Crystal Reports viewer working again on our Windows 2012 servers.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer for anyone... fix is simple but requires a manual change every time their is a patch\update for .NET Framework 4.6

Turns out the problem is that Crystal Reports looks for a folder that matches the version of the Framework including the "build".

The quickest way to manually fix this is go to the web page that has the Viewer and look at the source. You will find a line similar to /aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_xxx/crystalreportviewers13.....

Go to the servers hard drive and rename\copy that folder to the version it is looking for and you are back in business.